# Free audio and video playback using Direct3D9 and FMOD in VC++2010

Tags: c++, audio, video, textures, directx-9

I'd want to implement cutscene playback in my free game using a Direct3D9 texture and also play the sound in sync.

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express, DirectX9, FMOD targeting Windows XP or later.

I have essentialy no experience with video or audio.

I tried DirectShow but could not get it to compile and Bink is way out of my budget.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this: http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/

And maybe play the sound as a MP3 using FMOD.

Answer (score 0):

Using direct show you should be able to get the video to play and the audio with play with it. If not then you can use direct show for the video and then use FMOD for the sound. Programmatically though you will have to create the sounds and also the video to play and then set a trigger that the audio plays in the video playing state and then ends when video state has exited. For direct show you need these to start with to create you comobjects `////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // DirectShow COM Object Creation
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    IGraphBuilder           *videoGraph;
    IMediaControl           *videoControl;
    IMediaEvent         *videoEvent;
    IVideoWindow            *videoWindow;
    //HRESULT                       *isVideoDone;
    long evCode;
    LONG_PTR eventParam1, eventParam2;
    HWND                    hwnd;`

and then start it with a method like this in you cpp file  :

```
void InitVideo(LPCWSTR vidName)
```

{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

```
CoCreateInstance( CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder,
    (void**)&videoGraph);

videoGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl,
    (void**)&videoControl);

videoGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaEvent,
    (void**)&videoEvent);

// building a filter graph for our video
videoGraph->RenderFile(vidName, NULL);

//video window
videoControl->QueryInterface(IID_IVideoWindow,
    (void**)&videoWindow);

// setup the window
videoWindow->put_Owner((OAHWND)hwnd);

// Set the style
videoWindow->put_WindowStyle(WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE);

// Obtain the size of the window
RECT WinRect;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &WinRect);
//GetWindowRect(hwnd, &WinRect);

// Set the video size to the size of the window

videoWindow->SetWindowPosition(WinRect.left, WinRect.top, 
    WinRect.right, WinRect.bottom);

videoWindow->put_Visible(OATRUE);
```

}